# I am trying to pass a global variable through py files. Is this correct?

Tags: python, function

```
def mods(*arg):
    global mlist
    if not arg:
        mlist = [module for module in sorted(globals())]      
        return( [module for module in enumerate(mlist)]) 

     #easily delete by indices instead of typing out module name
     # i.e mods(18,19,20,21,22) deletes all those items quickly
    
    else:
        for iteration in arg:
            if type(iteration) == int:
                del globals()[mlist[iteration]]
            elif type(iteration) == str:
                del globals()[iteration]
            
        return([module for module in sorted(globals())],
                "-----------------------------------------------",
                "Deleted: "+
                str([mlist[iteration] if type(iteration) == int else iteration for iteration in arg]))
```

But now I want to define this handy dandy function in its own file so I can call it everytime I work on new code without copy pasting it each time. This works on calling the function with the full module name. But not via integers. Run both my codes for yourself, because I am not the greatest in explaining!
So:

```
# Now in its own file --- "pyfile1.py"

def mods(*arg):
    global mlist
    from inspect import currentframe
    if not arg:
        mlist = [module for module in sorted(currentframe().f_back.f_globals)
                 ]
        
        return(mlist)
    
    else:
        for i in arg:
            del currentframe().f_back.f_globals[i]
            
        return([module for module in sorted(currentframe().f_back.f_globals)],
               "-----------------------------------------------",
               "Deleted: "+
               str(arg[:]))

# Open new file: "pyfile2.py"

  from pyfile1 import *
  mods() # works
  mods("tensorflow") works
  mods(1,2,18,20) # having hard time coding this part
```

Issue is with my global mlist. Now I cant map the enumeration to a variable and then use that same mapping to delete. Because the variable just goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the function's return value to a module level variable.

```
#pyfile2.py
from pyfile1 import *
mlist = mods() # works
mlist , *stuff= mods("tensorflow") works
mlist, *stuff = mods(1,2,18,20) # having hard time coding this part
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for my module to somehow return the global mlist variable? I cant think of any. You would have to run the module in that frame itself....only then does it even create that variable..... I want to somehow just be able to call that module mods(1,2,3)

Comment: `[module for module in sorted(currentframe().f_back.f_globals)]` is a list comprehension that creates a new list your function never operates on a list in another scope.